# JPA Condition in JOIN

Tags: java, jpa, join, jpa-2.0

First off all, sorry for my english.

I want create a query with JPA, like this

```
select * 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
    and t2.field = 1
```

how to do the "`and t2.field = 1` " inside `join` (without `WHERE` clause)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL doesn't support that. HQL (the Hibernate JPQL implementation) has a `with` keyword though.